# Reduce output dimensions on LSTM keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

Below is my architecture of the model. The data is a time series which I need to predict only the last value, hence `return_sequences=False`.

But this is exactly what creates the problem here. I have been able to run the nnet using `sequences=True`, but it is not what I need to do.

I need an **input size (32,50,88)**=(batch_size,timesteps,features) 
and get **output size of (32,88)**=(batch_size,labels).

Features and labels have the same size, but it is irrelevant.

The error out of this code is:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 50, 88)

which is happening in the training phase (meaning, the architecture comes to be valid).

The data comes in chunks of (32,50,88) from a generator, also the labels have the same size. Since I use `keras`, I need to create the batches through the generator. I have tried to add a single (50,88) but simply it doesn't work.

**How could I have this kind of architecture, get the input of (32,50,88) but only get (32,88) as output?**

*In short, I need the timestep+50 prediction...I think..*

```
def note_model():
    visible = Input(shape=(50,88), batch_shape=(32,50,88))
    hidden1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(200, stateful=False, return_sequences=False,  kernel_regularizer=l1(10**(-4)), dropout=0.5))(visible)
    #flat = Flatten()(hidden1)
    output = Dense(88, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)

    model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
    print(model.summary())
    return model


    def train_note_model(model):
    checkpoint_path_notes = "1Layer-200units-loss=BCE-Model-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.2f}.hdf5"
    model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) #mean_squared_error
    monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=10, verbose=0, mode='min')
    reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.3, patience=10, min_lr=0.001)
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path_notes,monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
    model.fit_generator(training_generator(), steps_per_epoch=2, 
                        callbacks=[monitor, reduce_lr, checkpoint],
                        validation_data= validation_generator(), validation_steps= 2,
                        verbose=1, epochs=10, shuffle=True)

model_try = note_model()
train_note_model(model_try)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is correct, the issues is *when checking the target* which means that your `training_generator` is returning wrong target shapes.

Have a look at `print(next(training_generator()))` and ensure that it returns a tuple with shapes `(32, 50, 88), (32, 88)`.

Comment: My training generator returns (32,50,88) for the features and (32,50,88) for the labels. I think It should be this way, in order to learn the continuity of the values. Or should the labels be just (32,88) ? You helped me already, but could you clarify me this detail? Thanks!

Comment: You said you want to predict the last value so your labels need to be (32, 88), i.e. not a timeseries. You setup your network that way as well, you *read* a sequence and then make your prediction.